# Pub/Sub events with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement a pub/sub with Firebase Realtime Database for a distributed system. I want something like Amazon SQS, but I don't know how I can guarantee that only one subscriber will process the message.

Would transactions do the work? Is there a way to lock a row or something like that?

**Update**

Here is my current code for the subscriber, is this safe?

```
public class TaskToRun {
    private String id;
    private String data;
    private boolean running;
    //getters and setters
}

public class TaskSubscriber implements ChildEventListener{
    private Query reference;
    private LinkedList<TaskToRun> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private Object lockQueue = new Object();
    private final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(1, true);
    private boolean running;
    public TaskSubscriber(){
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks").orderByChild("running").equalTo(false);
    }
    public void start(){
        running = true;
        queue.clear();
        reference.addChildEventListener(this);
        AsyncTask t = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                while (running){
                    try {
                        available.acquire();
                        if(!running)
                            break;
                        TaskToRun task = null;
                        synchronized(lockQueue){
                            if(queue.size() > 0){
                                task = queue.pop();
                            }
                        }
                        if(task != null){

                            //Try to update the object to running
                            Transaction.Handler handler = new Transaction.Handler() {
                                private boolean canRun = false;
                                @Override
                                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                    canRun = false;

                                    TaskToRun t = mutableData.getValue(TaskToRun.class);
                                    if(t == null)
                                        return  Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    if(t.isRunning())
                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);

                                    t.setRunning(true);
                                    mutableData.setValue(t);
                                    canRun = true;
                                    return  Transaction.success(mutableData);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(canRun && databaseError == null) {
                                        runTask(dataSnapshot.getValue(TaskToRun.class));

                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks").child(task.getId()).runTransaction(handler);

                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        t.execute();
    }
    private void runTask(TaskToRun task) {
        Log.e("TASKS","Running task "+task.getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void stop(){
        running = false;
        reference.removeEventListener(this);
        synchronized (lockQueue) {
            queue.clear();
        }
        //Release all threads
        int usedPermits = 1 - available.availablePermits();
        available.release(usedPermits);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        synchronized (lockQueue){
            TaskToRun task = dataSnapshot.getValue(TaskToRun.class);
            task.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            if(!task.isRunning()){
                queue.addLast(task);
                available.release();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        synchronized (lockQueue){
            TaskToRun task = dataSnapshot.getValue(TaskToRun.class);
            task.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            if(task.isRunning()){
                for(int i = 0; i < queue.size();i++){
                    TaskToRun t  = queue.get(i);
                    if(t.getId().equals(task.getId())){
                        queue.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        synchronized (lockQueue){
            TaskToRun task = dataSnapshot.getValue(TaskToRun.class);
            task.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            if(task.isRunning()){
                for(int i = 0; i < queue.size();i++){
                    TaskToRun t  = queue.get(i);
                    if(t.getId().equals(task.getId())){
                        queue.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

Main code

```
new TaskSubscriber().start();
```

The code to publish

```
TaskToRun task = new TaskToRun();
task.setData("send_sms");
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks").push().setValue(task);
```

Comment: There are many techniques that will make that happen easily with firebase like push() ids, security rules and so much more. Please share some code and something that you might have already done then it will be much easier to guide you in right direction.

Comment: For a standard queue implementation, see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue.

Comment: I edited my answer with the code I thought, is this safe?